# I have problem with process in c code with argv parameters

Tags: c, compiler-errors, initialization, printf, srand

Gcc compiler messages:

`passing argument 1 of ‘srand’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]`

`too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]`

My code:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
void main(int argc,int* argv[])
{
    srand(argv[1]);
    srand(argv[2]);
    printf("I am orginal MY PID %d and MY PPID %d \n",getpid(),getppid());
    int pid,x,s,x1;
    pid=fork();
    if (pid!=0)//parent 
    {
        printf("I am parnet and My PID %d and My PPID %d /n",getpid(),getppid());
        for(int i=0 ;i<3;i++){
            s=rand();
            x=s%5;
            sleep(x);
            printf("parent sleep\n",x);
        }
        printf("the parent terminated with PID %d and PPID %d \n",getpid(),getppid());
    }
    else{//child
        printf("i'm a child with PID %d and PPID %d \n" ,getpid(),getppid());
      
        for(int i=0 ; i<3;i++){
            sleep(x1);
            s=rand();
            x1=s%5;
            }
            printf("child sleep \n",x1);
            printf("the child terminated with PID %d and PPID %d \n",getpid(),getppid());

    }
    

}
```

Comment: `argv` is an array of strings. The `srand()` argument must be an integer. Use `atoi()` to parse the string to an integer.

Comment: Why are you calling `srand()` twice? Only the last one has any effect.

Comment: In `printf("child sleep \n",x1);` you have an argument `x1`, but no `%d` format operator to print it.

Comment: `srand(argv[1]);` better as `srand(strtoul(argv[1], 0, 0));`.  Best for `srand()` to perform an _unsigned_ conversion.

Answer (score 0):

For starters the function `main` shall be declared like

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
```

instead of

```
void main(int argc,int* argv[])
```

In any case the expressions `argv[1]` and `argv[2]` have a pointer type. So these calls of the function `srand`

```
srand(argv[1]);
srand(argv[2]);
```

are invalid. The function is declared like

```
void srand(unsigned int seed);
```

That is it expects an integer instead of a pointer.

And in any case before using `argv[1]` and `argv[2]` you need to check the value of `argc`.

And calling the function twice sequentially does not make sense.

In these calls of `printf`

```
printf("parent sleep\n",x);
//...
printf("child sleep \n",x1);
```

you specified the redundant arguments `x` and `x1` that do not have  corresponding conversion specifiers in the format string.

Also you are using uninitialized variables as for example

```
sleep(x1);
```

The variable `x1` was not initialized.